# Unable to close the popup for Tkinter after entering the correct password

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

Unable to close the popup for Tkinter after entering the correct password. After entering the correct password the GUI is not closing.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack()

def myClick():
    password = "sunny567"
    get = e.get()
    if get == password:
        myLabel = Label(root, text=get)
        myLabel.pack()

    else:
        myLabel = Label(root, text="Entered Password is wrong. Please try again.")
        myLabel.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="Enter the password", command=myClick)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `root.destroy()` when password is correct.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

e = Entry(root, width=50)
e.pack()

def myClick():
    password = "sunny567"
    get = e.get()
    if get == password:
        root.destroy()  # close the root window
    else:
        myLabel.config(text="Entered Password is wrong. Please try again.")

myButton = Button(root, text="Enter the password", command=myClick)
myButton.pack()

myLabel = Label(root)
myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I gave wrong password multiple times, it gives on printing entered password is wrong below the submit button. How to avoid that?

Comment: There should be only one message below the button in my answer.  So what is the expected result you want actually?

Comment: For example for the first time if you enter the wrong password, it gives entered password is wrong and please try again. If you again enter the wrong password below the first attempt of wrong password it's giving the same like entered password is wrong. How to avoid that?

Comment: As I said my answer shows only one message below the button.  Yours will show multiple messages.